# Is there a reason to end this mission?

Tags: xcom-2

I'm on the mission where

> The Avenger has been shot down.

All the pods on the map are dead but reinforcements keep coming in. However, they keep dropping into the same area and are being destroyed on the turn they land.

There seems to be no timer so is there a reason not to wait here a while and farm them for loot and exp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, feel free to farm to your hearts content.

Answer (score 3):

You can farm on the map as long as you want until whenever you want to retreat. I used this opportunity to:

- Promote all of my squad members
- Farm resources, corpses, and also equipment drops (like weapon mods)

  - Great so you can sell them later on in the Black Market for extra supplies