# Can a soldier receive multiple promotions in a mission?

Tags: xcom-2

This question is inspired by an answer to [this question about reinforcements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/254739/99678). There, Michael Stum responded:

> feel free to farm to your hearts content.

If I find myself in a situation where enemies keep coming and I keep my soldiers around to kill the enemies *ad nauseam*, will they ever earn multiple promotions in a level?

I've seen the same question for [Enemy Unknown](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/90106/99678), so I would guess the answer is no, but the behavior could have changed.

Comment: The accepted answer below is probably wrong with the current version given that there's a mod to actually enable this: https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=785522241 Note that the mod is dated 23 Oct.

Answer (score 7):

This might be anecdotal, but yes, you can:

I ranked all my squad members to Colonel on the downed Avenger mission, by simply refusing to destroy the signal beacon and farming the incoming assault drops by setting up Overwatch traps.

Took me an hour to do so. After returning to the Avenger I was greeted with multiple rank ups after promoting the soldier (meaning went all the way from Squaddie to Colonel)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I'll hold off accepting for a little bit just in case, but thanks!

Comment: I messed up several times which caused a long delay because after a while you just get an endless amount of stun troopers (and those suck!)

Comment: This seems a bit exploity though. I preferred the previous game's solution. you would still get the XP after a promotion, but only _up until_ the next cap. So if you got your 500XP promotion in a mission, and the next promotion would be at 750XP, then it would cap itself during that mission at 749XP. Thus guaranteeing a maximum of one promotion per mission.

Comment: Hmm, it's kinda strange. All of my soldiers was promoted on this mission, but only with one promotion.